# event listener on a new browser tab gets unbound when the originating window is closed

Tags: javascript

Following is code I have to create a new browser tab when a user clicks a button which binds an event handler to the new tab's resize event. The resizing works fine as long as the original window is kept open, but as soon as I close the original window, the new tab resizing doesn't do anything anymore.

```
 var tab = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
 if (tab) {                        
    tab.addEventListener("load", function () {                            
    //console log in the new tab records 'resized!' when tab is resized 
    //as long as the original window is kept open
      tab.addEventListener('resize', function () { tab.console.log('resized!') });
    }
    tab.document.close();
 }
```

The question is, how to permanently bind that event to the new window so that it persists even when the old window is closed?

Comment: Is there a question here? You want the new window to continue firing the resize event after the parent closes?

Comment: kind of guessing here, but if that code you pasted is from window one, then the behavior you see makes sense.  The code for the event is stored on that page, so if you close the page, it goes away.